# raster::focal fails on a selection of invalid row in R

Tags: raster, r, focal-statistics

I try to compute the proportion of 0 in an area of 30km around a given pixel.
The raster has a resolution of 100m and it is the map of France.

For this, I use the function `focal()` of the `raster` package (package version: 2.9.23). The analyse works well on a subset of the raster but not on the full raster. The error message is the following:

```
> Error in .local(x, row, nrows, ...) : validRow(x, row) is not TRUE
```

### Looking for the `.local` function:

```
getMethod("focal", signature = "RasterLayer")
```

I find `.local()` but did not find its source on
[github](https://github.com/rspatial/raster) or in the [source code](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.9-23/source).

### validRow function

The function `validRow()` checks that a number of rows is valid regarding the
raster.

```
r <- raster()
validRow(r, c(-1, 1, 100, 10000))
# -1 is obviously not valid and 10000 neither because the nb of rows of the
#raster is 180
```

I did not succeed to identify what operation in the `focal()` function can lead
to this error.

The problem could be related to this [open issue in github](https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/56).

### Trying to reproduce the error

The most annoying part of the problem is that I do not succeed to reproduce the
error with a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(raster)

# Get France raster at 100m resolution
p <- getData(name = "GADM", country = "france", level = 0)
p <- spTransform(p, CRSobj = CRS("+init=epsg:2154"))
r_total <- raster(p, resolution = 100)

# Crop and put dumb data
r <- crop(r_total, extent(98900, 150000, 6100000, 6150000))
nbcell <- ncell(r)
# Set values 0 or 1:
r <- setValues(r, rbinom(n = nbcell, size = 1, prob = .9))
# Put some NAs:
values(r)[sample(1:nbcell, size = .9*nbcell)] <- NA

# Compute the focal
fw <- focalWeight(r, 30000,"circle")
test <- focal(r,w = fw, fun = "sum", na.rm = TRUE, pad = TRUE, padValue = NA)
```

If I could reproduce the error, I hope that It will help to identify the problem
with the real dataset.

Comment: Have you tried `focal(r[[1]])`? Wondering if your raster was in a brick or stack? like this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258358/how-to-fix-hasvaluesx-is-not-true-error-in-raster-package

Comment: @GISKid Unfortunately, the answer you kindly linked to refer to another type of error. And the raster is a single raster layer, not in a brick or stack.

Comment: Your focal values represent weights. On the object resulting from `focalWeight` try `fw[fw > 0] <- 1` this will solve one issue that may have not arisen just yet and may even mitigate the issue at hand.